# when associations should be embedded or referenced Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, database

I am using mongodb in my rails app with odm [mongoid](http://mongoid.org)

My questions are easy:

a) when associations between objects should be embedded or referenced?

b) how does this affect the application performance?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It was discussed multiple times. Short answer: "it all depends on your app, data and access patterns".

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

Comment: Another link [http://openmymind.net/2012/1/30/MongoDB-Embedded-Documents-vs-Multiple-Collections/](http://openmymind.net/2012/1/30/MongoDB-Embedded-Documents-vs-Multiple-Collections/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referenced relationships require multiple db lookups; embedded relationships don't. But referenced relationships are easier to work with (especially if you are just starting out with your app and/or with mongo). I would recommend that you stay with referenced relationships until you have a better sense of the shape of your app and your data needs; at that point you can denormalize your data by switching some of those referenced relationships to embedded.

I would also recommend https://github.com/dzello/mongoid_alize to help with denormalization.